# Move line from output to the front of output or custom reordering

Tags: shell, grep, sort

I have a command `find "$PWD" -name __openerp__.py|awk -F/ -vOFS=/ 'NF-=2'|sort -u` and I want to take a certain line containing `/web/addons` and push it to the front of output then do the same with `/openerp/addons` making so that line with `/openerp/addons` would be first and line with `/web/addons` would be second.

I figured to use grep with that input and from the same output - grep with wildcard and exclude, but yet to figure out how to pass pipe output to multiple greps. Also there is probably multiple ways of doing this.

So right now I get:

```
<my path>/addons
<my path>/development
<my path>/external
<my path>/server/openerp/addons
<my path>/web/addons
```

And I want it to become:

```
<my path>/server/openerp/addons
<my path>/web/addons
<my path>/addons
<my path>/development
<my path>/external
```

P.S. Reversal of sort will not solve this

Comment: This will not work in a pipeline: it needs to buffer all output lines until it finds the ones you're interested in before outputting anything.

Comment: actually I'm fine to hold buffer in /tmp/. I'm mainly interested in it being one liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I did it by saving to `/tmp/` and then executing grep on it few times:

```
find "$PWD" -name '__openerp__.py' | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ 'NF-=2' | sort -u > /tmp/openerp_addon_list.txt ; (egrep '/openerp/addons|/web/addons$' /tmp/openerp_addon_list.txt; egrep -v "/openerp/addons|/web/addons|/openerp/test" /tmp/openerp_addon_list.txt)
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/server/openerp/addons
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/web/addons
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/addons
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/development
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/external
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/groups/account-invoice-report
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/groups/banking-addons
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/groups/partner-contact-management
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/groups/sale-reports
/home/domas/Sources/openerp/7.0/groups/webkit-utils
```

Comment: Did this work for you? Because on my system it only prints two lines given your sample input: `<my path>` followed by `<my path>/server`.

Comment: yep it works. also I pass output to `| tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$/ /' | tr " " "\n"` but this is a bit out of this question boundaries. Maybe my sample is wrong in this case.

Comment: Edited and added output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here but if all you want is to have the line with `/openerp/addons` to be first and `/web/addons` to be second, why not just something like this:

```
find "$PWD" -name '__openerp__.py' | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ 'NF-=2' | 
  sed 's#^\(.*/openerp/addons.*\)#aaa%\1#; s#^\(.*/web/addons.*\)#aab%\1#' | 
   sort -u | sed 's/^aa.%//'
```

Not particularly clever or elegant but this will simply add `aaa%` to the beginning of lines containing `/openerp/addons` and `aab%` to the beginning of lines containing `/web/addons`. The last `sed` removes them again after sorting. Assuming you have no files whose name starts with `aa.%`, that should have the desired result.

Or, you could use a simple perl one-liner that also does the job of `sort -u`:

```
find fafa/ | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ 'NF-=2' | 
 perl -ne 's#^(.*/openerp/addons)#aaa%$1#; s#^(.*/web/addons)#aab%$1#; $k{$_}++; 
            END{for (sort keys(%k)){s/^aa.%//; print }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111475/move-line-from-output-to-the-front-of-output-or-custom-reordering#comment172628_111475), pipelines are not the way to go; at least not with a tool as simple as `grep`. I would use a more powerful tool, such as Python or Perl, for this. Here's a Perl filter that might help:

```
your command | perl -ne '
    if($already_found_lines){
        print # print the current line as is
    } else{
        if   (m{/web/addons}    ) { $web=$_     and $found_web++    }
        elsif(m{/openerp/addons}) { $openerp=$_ and $found_openerp++}
        else                      { push @buffer,$_                 }
        $already_found_lines = ($found_web and $found_openerp);
        if($already_found_lines)  { print "${openerp}$web";print for @buffer}
    }'
```

This tested correctly with your sample input.

Comment: Thanks, but I do have a code with python, but as mentioned I just wanted it to make bash one liner. So in my case although this is great and works - it's not something I will end up using.

Comment: @JackLeo Technically, this _is_ a one-liner (whatever that may mean) `:)`. It's not Bash, though, and neither is your solution, which simply uses Bash to invoke external tools.

Comment: Well yes you're right. I give you that. Just for something as simple perl seems to be bit of a overkill. I could just pasted the same python code to '' and that would be a one liner as well.

Comment: @JackLeo I think the "overkillness" of this approach is highly debatable. Would using a simple Python code instead of 4 tool invocations (along with a subshell) be overkill? Also, the higher level code has the advantage of being more readable (in my opinion, at least).

Comment: yes I do agree with you, but then why even bother with something passing info to perl/python code while it can get the same info itself.

Comment: @JackLeo By that logic, no one should ever use `perl` or `python` in a pipeline, which would severely undermine their usefulness.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. You need `$already_found_lines = ($found_web and $found_openerp);` without the parentheses, the test returns true if `$found_web` is defined. Also, you might want to consider a simpler version: `perl -ne 'if (m{/openerp/addons}) {$openerp=$_;} elsif (m{/web/addons}) {$web=$_;} else {push @buffer,$_} END{print "$openerp$web"; print for sort @buffer;}`

Comment: @terdon Thanks for catching and fixing the bug. The simpler version would buffer the whole thing and not print out until the end. My version will only buffer for as long as it needs to.

Comment: True, that might be a problem for large results.